# How to best use ApolloClient / InMemoryCache and enable Cache on demand for API's?

Tags: reactjs, caching, async-await, apollo

I want to refractor the current code to use the ApolloClient constructor to cache information and only query for new data if the requesting data isn't already cache –

Currently I'm using fetchPolicy to cache users Id but from what I've seen there is a way to cache using apollo.

```
async fetchRecipients(userIds: string[]) {

  //TODO: How to refactor and use apollo cache?

  const result = await client?.query({
    query: MembersBySFIDs,
    variables: {sfids: userIds},
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
  });

  if (result?.data?.membersBySFIDs) {
    await dispatch.newChatMessage.setRecipients(result.data.membersBySFIDs);
  } else {
    throw new Error('Members not found');
  }
}
```

Here is what I tried so far,
I don't think I am using it correctly, any help is appreciated:

```
import { InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

const result = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

async fetchRecipients(userIds: string[]) {
  const result = await client?.query({
    query: MembersBySFIDs,
    variables: {sfids: userIds},
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
  });

  if (result?.data?.membersBySFIDs) {
    await dispatch.newChatMessage.setRecipients(result.data.membersBySFIDs);
  } else {
    throw new Error('Members not found');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more info in the question on what is your requirement? ApolloClient has a [constructor](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.constructor) for cache policy and also has [Query hooks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy) that provide cache policy.

Comment: @NagarajTantri I want to refractor the current code to use the ApolloClient constructor to cache information and only query for new data if the requesting data isn't already cache

Comment: So, is your question, "How to best use ApolloClient and enable Cache on demand for API's?"

Comment: @NagarajTantri correct

Comment: they have a whole doc around configuring cache: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/ and there are many different options which becomes useful only if we know the entire requirement in your application. Like, when to specify custom primary keys, etc. What I am hinting at is that your question is very generic and it would be good to get more details on your application requirements.

Comment: @NagarajTantri can you provide an example. I took a look at the examples they had and im still a little lost on how I should switch my code to work

Comment: so the above links do have those examples. What is unclear is your current code. I mean, for us to even suggest the way forward, we don't know how your current code looks like and what challenges you face.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default behavior of `client.query` by configuring `ApolloClient`'s the default `fetchPolicy` to `cache-first` in `defaultOptions` as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#example-defaultoptions-object).

Something like this:

```
import { InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: "cache-first"
    }
  }
});


async fetchRecipients(userIds: string[]) {
  const result = await client?.query({
    query: MembersBySFIDs,
    variables: {sfids: userIds},
  });

  // do whatever you want with the result here
 
}
```

Hope you found this helpful.